# Paste data from one workbook to another based on searching column for "C" or "D"

Tags: vba, excel

I have run into a roadblock. I have a document that gets a status given to an audit item (circle, triangle, x). Currently, users have to manually write up the problem on another document. I want to auto populate this other document based on the selection in the cell.

In my example, cell string to review is V27:AD195. If any of these cells include "C" or "D" then it would return the value from Column "B" onto the PFUS Sample document's next available empty cell.

I am having trouble with my programming idea getting it to work...I don't want/need to copy the entire row just the cell in B column.

How do I upload the example?
My original programming idea is to use

```
Sub Sample()
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim copyFrom As Range
Dim lRow As Long '<~~ Not Integer. Might give you error in higher versions of excel
Dim strSearch As String

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Test")

strSearch = "D"

With ws1

'~~> Remove any filters
.AutoFilterMode = False

'~~> I am assuming that the names are in Col A
'~~> if not then change A below to whatever column letter
lRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With .Range("E1:E" & lRow)
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strSearch & "*"
Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
End With

'~~> Remove any filters
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With

'~~> Destination File
Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Sample.xlsx")
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ws2
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
After:=.Range("A1"), _
Lookat:=xlPart, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
MatchCase:=False).Row
Else
lRow = 1
End If

copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
End With

wb2.Save
wb2.Close
End Sub
```

But I am having trouble manipulating this to work for my specific need because it copies the entire row. Any ideas? Beginner VBA here with limited knowledge but can pick up quick.

Comment: Post the bits of code you have problems with into your question and format it as code. No need to post the whole project as a file. If a file is really required, use one of the many free file sharing sites.

Comment: I tried to post images but it said I didn't have "repuation"...sorry new here.

Comment: Who said anything about images? Post your code. Post images or other files on a file sharing site. Post a link. If you are not allowed to post a link, post the URL of the link. Do I really have to spell it out?

Comment: Well I was trying to post a screen shot of my document examples to further explain what I was doing. I find your comment to be rude and unnecessary on a help forum.

Comment: This site is not a forum.

Answer (score 1):

teylyn may have been a little abrupt but his complaint is correct. You are making it very difficult for anyone to help you by posting a large chunk of code that does not appear to relate to your question. If you had located the piece of code that was not doing what you wanted/expected and created a small example based on that faulty code you would probably have received an answer within minutes.

---

**Issues with your code**

"*In my example, cell string to review is V27:AD195.*" By "cell string" do you mean "cell range"? Your code performs an AutoFilter on column E. How does this relate to `V27:AD195`?

You say you want either "C" or "D" but you only search for "D".

I rarely use `AutoFilter` and am not an expert. To me, this seems an unusual way to search a multi-column range for multiple values.  You search for `=*D*`.  My understanding is you can either search for a particular string, or blanks or non-blanks. I do not think there is a wild card facility which I assume is the purpose of the asterisks.  I do not know why the equals is there.

If you are only interested in column B, why `Set copyFrom = ... EntireRow`?

You have two separate requirements.  (1) Identify rows containing either "C" or "D".  (2) Move the value of column B of each of those rows to another worksheet.  You do not check that you have successfully achieved requirement 1 before attempting to achieve requirement 2.

---

**My solution to requirement 1**

There are many answers on StackOverflow that show how to move values from one worksheet to another so I have ignored requirement 2.

Requirement 1 is trickier and I have not seen a similar question.

I do not believe there is any sensible way of achieving requirement 1 with `AutoFilter`.  If anyone knows different, I will be interested in knowing how since it means I have misunderstood the full capabilities of `AutoFilter`.

I could have used VBA to search the cell values but I believe `Find`, which will search for a string within a cell, will be faster. I have not tested this but the general advice is not to write VBA to duplicate Excel functionality. There is a `Find All` available from the keyboard but there is no VBA equivalent. However, I do not believe a VBA `Find All` would be helpful in this case.

The first thing I want to say about the code below is that it is full of `Debug.Print` statements.  I did not write this code in one go.  I stepped through the code and used the Debug.Print statements to check that each section did what I wanted before moving onto the next section.  Also there are a lot of `Debug.Assert False` all but one of which has been commented out.  When I start, I place a `Debug.Assert False` statement at the head of every path through the code.  When one of these statements is reached, execution stops.  I step on one statement and then comment out the `Debug.Assert False`.  If there are any `Debug.Assert False` statement still active when I have finished, either I have not adequately tested my code or my design is faulty and the code cannot be reached.  Either way, I have more work to do.  There are other ways of achieving the same objectives but these techniques work for me.

Your code will have to look for "C" and then look for "D" and then merge the results.  It is easier to use an array of search values in such cases than to duplicate the code so I have:

```
SearchValue = Array("C", "D", "Z", "G")
```

You only want "C" and "D" but I wanted to properly test my code.  There are no "Z"s amid my test data so this array allowed me to test that the complete absence of a value is handled correctly.

I have two other arrays (RowFirst and RowNext) which I size to match SearchValue.

My test data is:

```
 1 H     I    J   K    L    M       G
 2 H     I    J   D    L    M       N
 3 A     B    C   K    E    F   
 4 H     I    J   K    L    M       N
 5 O     P    Q   R    S    T       U
 6 V     W    X   Y    X    ABCDEF  ABC
 7 DEF   AD   A   B    E    F       G
 8 H     CAB  ABD DEF  L    M       N
 9 C     I    J   K    L    M       N
10 H     I    J   K    L    M       N
11 H     I    D   K    L    M       N
12 H     G    J   K    L    M       N
13 H     I    G   K    L    M       N
14 H     I    J   D    L    M       N
15 H     I    J   K    L    M       N
16 H     I    J   D    L    M       N
```

The first significant block of code, searches for the first occurrences of the four values and store values to give:

```
SearchValue "C"  "D"  "Z"  "G"
RowFirst     3    2    0    1
RowNext      3    2    0    1
```

The code uses `Find` repeatedly and it will eventually loop.  When, in the the main loop, `Find` tell me it has found "C" on row 3 (the value in RowFirst), I know it has looped and every occurrence of "C" has been found and processed.  `RowNext = 0` in the "Z" column tells the code not to look for "Z"

The main loop first processes the match just found.  The lowest value in `RowNext` is 1 so that is the next (first) row with one of these values.  I record 1 in array RowMatch.

The code then updates `RowNext` for the next rows containing the search values after row 1.  For "C" and "D", the next rows have already been found.  There is to be no search for "Z".  The next "G" is on row 7.  So the arrays become:

```
SearchValue "C"  "D"  "Z"  "G"
RowFirst     3    2    0    1
RowNext      3    2    0    7
```

When a `Find` loops, the `RowNext` for the value is set to 0 to indicate that value is finished.  The main loop continues until all the `RowNext` values are 0.

For my test data, the rows with matching values (as stored in RowMatch) are:

```
1 2 3 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 14 16
```

If your data matched mine and if you were interested in "G", these are the rows whose column B you would move to the new worksheet.

I hope the above explanation, the comments in the code and the output from the `Debug.Print` statements are sufficient for you to understand the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub FindMatchingRows()

  Dim ColRightToSearch As Long
  Dim InxValueCrnt As Long
  Dim InxMatchCrnt As Long
  Dim InxMatchMax As Long
  Dim RngMatch As Range
  Dim RowBotToSearch As Long
  Dim RngToSearch As Range
  Dim RowFirst() As Long
  Dim RowMatch() As Long
  Dim RowNext() As Long
  Dim RowFirstCrnt As Long
  Dim SearchValue() As Variant
  Dim WshtToSearch As Worksheet

  ' Specify search values
  SearchValue = Array("C", "D", "Z", "G")

  ' Define worksheet and range to search.  Change to your values
  Set WshtToSearch = Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set RngToSearch = WshtToSearch.Range("A1:Z50")

  ' ReDim Preserve is a slow statement so I do not want to use it more often than
  ' necessary. When I do not know how many values I will want to store in an array I
  ' start with as many entries as I think will be enough and only enlarge the array
  ' if I fill it.
  ReDim RowMatch(1 To 100)
  InxMatchMax = 0   ' No rows with any of the values found yet

  ' One entry for each entry on SearchValue
  ' Search always start after the specified "after" cell, continues to the end of the
  ' range, loops to beginning of the range and continues to the "after" cell.
  ' RowFirst() is used to detect Find looping and finding the first row again.
  ' RowNext() records the most recent search.
  ReDim RowFirst(LBound(SearchValue) To UBound(SearchValue))
  ReDim RowNext(LBound(SearchValue) To UBound(SearchValue))

  ' Identify bottom range and rightmost column of range to be searched.
  ' See below for the use made of these values
  RowBotToSearch = RngToSearch.Row + RngToSearch.Rows.Count - 1
  ColRightToSearch = RngToSearch.Column + RngToSearch.Columns.Count - 1

  Debug.Print "Bottom right cell is ("; RowBotToSearch & ", " & ColRightToSearch & ")"

  ' Initialise RowFirst and RowNext with the first row, if any, containing each
  ' search value.  Each search must start after the bottom right cell of the search
  ' range so the search starts in the first cell of the range
  RowFirstCrnt = 0      ' The first row containing any of the values
  For InxValueCrnt = LBound(SearchValue) To UBound(SearchValue)

    Set RngMatch = RngToSearch.Find(What:=SearchValue(InxValueCrnt), _
                                    After:=WshtToSearch.Cells(RowBotToSearch, ColRightToSearch), _
                                    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                    SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    If RngMatch Is Nothing Then
      ' This value not found within range
      'Debug.Assert False            ' Not tested
      Debug.Print SearchValue(InxValueCrnt) & " not found within range"
      RowNext(InxValueCrnt) = 0
    Else
      ' This value found within range
      'Debug.Assert False            ' Not tested
      Debug.Print SearchValue(InxValueCrnt) & " found on row " & _
                  RngMatch.Row & " in column " & RngMatch.Column
      RowNext(InxValueCrnt) = RngMatch.Row  ' First row containing this value
      RowFirst(InxValueCrnt) = RngMatch.Row
      If RowFirstCrnt = 0 Then
        ' First value found so first row found with matching value
        'Debug.Assert False            ' Not tested
        RowFirstCrnt = RngMatch.Row
      ElseIf RowFirstCrnt > RngMatch.Row Then
        ' This value found on earlier row than previous best
        'Debug.Assert False            ' Not tested
        RowFirstCrnt = RngMatch.Row
      End If
    End If

  Next

  Debug.Print "First rows: ";
  For InxValueCrnt = LBound(SearchValue) To UBound(SearchValue)
    If RowFirst(InxValueCrnt) = 0 Then
      'Debug.Assert False            ' Not tested
      Debug.Print " " & SearchValue(InxValueCrnt) & " not found ";
    Else
      'Debug.Assert False            ' Not tested
      Debug.Print " " & SearchValue(InxValueCrnt) & " on row "; RowFirst(InxValueCrnt) & " ";
    End If
  Next
  Debug.Print

  Do While RowFirstCrnt > 0

    Debug.Print "Next row with a match is " & RowFirstCrnt

    ' Record this match
    InxMatchMax = InxMatchMax + 1
    If UBound(RowMatch) < InxMatchMax Then
      'Debug.Assert False            ' Not tested
      ReDim Preserve RowMatch(1 To 100 + UBound(RowMatch))
    End If
    RowMatch(InxMatchMax) = RowFirstCrnt

    ' Now look for further matches

    RowFirstCrnt = 0       ' NO match found so far

    For InxValueCrnt = LBound(SearchValue) To UBound(SearchValue)

      If RowNext(InxValueCrnt) = 0 Then
        ' Either this value was not found or all occurrences of this value
        ' have already been found and recorded
        'Debug.Assert False            ' Not tested
      ElseIf RowNext(InxValueCrnt) > RowMatch(InxMatchMax) Then
        ' The next occurrence of this value is after the most recent matching
        ' row so this is still the next occurrence of this value
        If RowFirstCrnt = 0 Then
          ' Could be next matching row
          'Debug.Assert False            ' Not tested
          Debug.Print "First possible next match " & SearchValue(InxValueCrnt) & _
                      " on row " & RowNext(InxValueCrnt)
          RowFirstCrnt = RowNext(InxValueCrnt)
        ElseIf RowFirstCrnt > RowNext(InxValueCrnt) Then
          ' This value found on earlier row than previous best
          'Debug.Assert False            ' Not tested
          Debug.Print "New next match " & SearchValue(InxValueCrnt) & _
                      " on row " & RowNext(InxValueCrnt)
          RowFirstCrnt = RowNext(InxValueCrnt)
        End If
      Else
        'Debug.Assert False            ' Not tested
        ' Need to search again starting at the end of RowMatch(inxMatchMax)
        ' Note I cannot use FindNext because it continues the most recent
        ' and this code is performing different Finds

        Set RngMatch = RngToSearch.Find(What:=SearchValue(InxValueCrnt), _
                                        After:=WshtToSearch.Cells(RowMatch(InxMatchMax), ColRightToSearch), _
                                        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                        SearchDirection:=xlNext)

        If RngMatch Is Nothing Then
          ' This should not be possible since we are only searching for value know to be present
          Debug.Assert False            ' Not tested
        Else
          'Debug.Assert False            ' Not tested
          Debug.Print SearchValue(InxValueCrnt) & " found on row " & _
                      RngMatch.Row & " in column " & RngMatch.Column
          If RngMatch.Row = RowFirst(InxValueCrnt) Then
            ' Have looped back to first occurrence.  All rows for this value
            ' found and recorded
            'Debug.Assert False            ' Not tested
            RowNext(InxValueCrnt) = 0
            Debug.Print SearchValue(InxValueCrnt) & " has looped"
          Else
            ' New value found
            'Debug.Assert False            ' Not tested
            RowNext(InxValueCrnt) = RngMatch.Row
            If RowFirstCrnt = 0 Then
              ' First value found so first row found with matching value
              'Debug.Assert False            ' Not tested
              RowFirstCrnt = RngMatch.Row
            ElseIf RowFirstCrnt > RngMatch.Row Then
              ' This value found on earlier row than previous best
              'Debug.Assert False            ' Not tested
              RowFirstCrnt = RngMatch.Row
            End If
          End If  ' Process successful Find
        End If  ' Process result of Find
      End If  ' Decide if to search for this value
    Next InxValueCrnt

  Loop

  Debug.Print "Rows with matching values:";
  For InxMatchCrnt = 1 To InxMatchMax
    Debug.Print " " & RowMatch(InxMatchCrnt);
  Next
  Debug.Print

End Sub
```

Comment: I really didn't know what code to use that is why I just pasted the whole code I was tinkering with. I have nearly no experience with VBA. I have my first class on monday. 

This is what I was trying to say earlier. Here is my sheet one
[link](http://s23.postimg.org/csu8ggzob/workbook_A.png)

Here is my sheet 2
[link](http://s23.postimg.org/uhlz83bff/Workbook_B.png)

Comment: If you have just started VBA classes, this problem is a little advanced; couldn't you have found something simpler as a first problem.  There is little I can do with the two links.  Post some real data if I have misunderstood its format but not a image full of N/As.  Have you tried my code on your data?  Does it find the correct rows?  Do you understand my advice about developing code?

Comment: I understand it is way advanced but my employer has assigned me to complete this (I am a dept manager) and I do not have any member who is capable of completing the task and my IT group does not do VBA programing. I did try to use your code in my sheet and when I ran the code I did not see that it did anything so I assume it is my screw up somewhere. 

Here is a file with actual data
Data Source
http://www53.zippyshare.com/v/99320854/file.html
File I want to paste to.
http://www53.zippyshare.com/v/33144810/file.html

Comment: The first three statements after the `Dim` statements define the search values, the search worksheet and the search range.  Have you changed these for your data?  This macro does not change anything.  It finds every row that contains one of the search values.  It ends by outputting to the Immediate Window a list of those rows.  There is no point worrying about moving values unless the correct rows are being identified.

Comment: If I understand _Checksheet Sandbox.xlsm_ correctly, you plan to set Z28 to the range to be searched.  This does not seem to match the current value which is to be selected from "O", "D", "C" or "N/A".  Also Z28 is within the area to be searched.  Are V and AD fixed left and right columns?  Is 28 a fixed top row?  Is 195 a variable end row?

Comment: There appear to be an increasing number of employers like yours.  Because anyone can find anything on the web, it is no longer necessary to train people.  There are also companies (con artists) that will promise to train you to program in a day which adds to the myth that no training is necessary.

Comment: Regarding employers...AMEN! Our IT are nothing more than glorified Geek Squad. ANYWHO! The cells that are shaded black are not allowed to be answered at the stage where they are shaded black, they have to wait until later or are answered earlier. V and AD should never change unless more visits are added (I am quite sure I could manipulate the code then) and same goes for top row 28 and end row 195.

Comment: Every time I look at your workbook or read your text I have more questions. There is a limit on the number of comments like this we are allowed before we are expected to move the conversation to a chat room. Unfortunately you do not have the reputation necessary for visiting a chat room. If you visit my profile you will find an email address. If you are willing to continue this conversation via email, send me an email.